# Zener diodes in series

Tags: diodes, zener

[image]

Hello,
In this problem, i am not able to understand how I2 is getting replaced by I01. More over, will these zener diodes become ON as the applied voltage is less than Vz?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you converted your images to Mathjax which is much easier to read.  Also show what you already understand so people can help better.

Answer (score 4):

Because the zener voltage is 10V, and the applied voltage only 9V, so the two diodes all are not ON. They are series, so the current flow in them should be limited by the smaller reverse saturation current, that is, \$I_{o1}\$.

Comment: For what values of Va , both diodes be on? 20V minimum?

Comment: Yes, but the term ON it not so precise. Because you can define the ON current to 5mA, or 10mA, or else. Apparently the two diodes in your question are not same, so in practical applications, you'd better check their datasheets carefully.